# ExtJS 7: Unable to edit cell value that is in a subgrid, i.e., a grid within a grid row

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I am trying to put an editable grid within a grid row in ExtJs 7 using the modern toolkit, but am unable to update the subgrid cell values. The original values are shown after the cell loses focus.

I have created a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33id) of the scenario in abstract. See app/view/main/Main.js line 41 for the problem point:

```
                columns: [
                    {text: 'Foot', dataIndex: 'foot'},
// Edits are not shown after cell loses focus
                    {text: 'Condition', dataIndex: 'condition', editor: true},
                ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted the config a little and everything worked. `expandedField` is not needed, you are not using `rowexpander`. And you forgot the `editor` plugin for nested `grid`

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33im)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the need for the editing plugin on the nested grid. Sadly, there appears to be a bug when the parent grid plugin uses `triggerEvent: 'singletap'`.